# What's the 60's b&w movie where aliens have needles grow out of fingers and victims disappear in a funnel of sand?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, alien-invasion

White thin-skinned aliens with large heads have needles grow out of their fingers just before stabbing their victims, then retract. Drops of 'venom' fall from the tips.  They (victims) and/or aliens (can't remember) disappear when the dirt/sand opens up bigger and bigger; reminds me of the funnel shape made in an hour glass.

Answer (score 7):

I think you might be thinking of two different films.  The large-headed aliens with the retractable needles on the fingertips are from [Invasion of the Saucer Men](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050545/), (1957), and the "venom" turns out to be alcohol.

> A teenage couple making out in the woods accidentally runs over an
>   alien creature with their car. The creature's hand falls off, but it
>   comes alive, and, with an eye growing out of it, begins to stalk the
>   teens. Meanwhile, Joe the town drunk wants to store the body in his
>   refrigerator, but **some of the alien's buddies inject alcohol into his
>   system**, and Joe dies of an overdose.

The movie is available on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjtASrKtpos).  The aliens don't have much screen time, so check out their highlight reel [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnMNHB5L9Wc).

The aliens capturing humans in sand pits are from the original [Invaders From Mars](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0045917/), (1953).

> One night, young David McLean sees a spaceship crash into a nearby
>   sandpit. His father goes to investigate, but comes back changed. Where
>   once he was cheerful and affectionate, he's now sullen and snarlingly
>   rude. **Others fall into the sandpit** and begin acting like him: cold,
>   ill-tempered and conspiratorial.

The movie is available on Youtube, and one of the scenes in question is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSm-W43B4Mc#t=2418).

Comment: Sorry for the delay.... I think you are right! I don't remember Invaders being in color but that looks like it.  Thanks.